# Can I apply and execute a code from a different document?

Tags: vba, visio

Is there a way to have two documents where the first document has all the code and functions that will execute and apply on the second document?

For example: Doc 1 has a button and all of the code, and when I press that button, it will draw shapes on doc 2.

I was wondering if DocumentOpened is the fitting method. Any help or tip would be appreciated. Thank you!

PS. My other question was closed so I had to make a new one...

Comment: Please include the code you tried using in your question.

Comment: Excel XLAMs are files that contain protected VBA code as you describe, but Visio does not have a similar concept.

Comment: You should be able to reference a Visio another Visio document tho. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.documents

Comment: @braX I don't have a code. I'm currently designing how to write the code once I understand that it's possible to use and reference two documents at the same time.

Comment: @braX Thanks! So it is possible to have a code that can work on any document I open (without having to rewrite the whole code in all the new docs)?

Comment: Correct. As with any Office product, you can use the open application object to reference the document collection for that application.

Comment: @braX Is there a specific function I can use to reference the new document i'll open? Do I use DocumentOpened?

Answer (score 1):

As with any Office product, you can use the open application object to reference the document collection for that application.

Also, when you execute the `Documents.Open` function (or `.Add` function for new files) it will return a valid `Document` object. You then use that object to perform other operations.

[Visio Documents.Open Method Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.documents.open)

```
' open existing document
Dim viDoc as Object
Set viDoc = Documents.Open(sFilename)
```

or

```
' create new document
Dim viDoc as Object
Set viDoc = Documents.Add(sFilename)
```

Comment: thank you! Where should this code be written (doc 1 or 2)? ex. In my case, document 1 has a button with the code where if it's clicked, it will create a shape on document 2.